# Proving that $[NH:N] | |H|$ and $[NH:N] | [G:N]$.

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ be a finite group, $N \lhd G$ and $H<G$. Prove that $NH < G$ and $[NH:N]$ is a divisor of $|H|$ and of $[G:N]$. What can we say about $N$ and $H$ if $(|H|, [G:N]) = 1$?.

I already proved that $NH < G$, but I don't know how to prove the other assertion. I thought in using Lagrange's theorem but I think I can't use it directly since it would say that $|G|=[G:N]|N|$, $|G|=[G:H]|H|$ and $|NH|=|NH : N|$, but this equations don't relate $[NH:N]$, $|H|$ and $[G:N]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: try to prove that $|NH|=|N||H|/|N \cap H| (*)$. Also, $[G:NH][NH:N]=[G:N]$.

> Suppose you have proven that $|NH|=|N||H|/|N \cap H|$, then $[NH:N]=|NH|/|N|=|H|/|N \cap H|=[H:N \cap H]$, and this is clearly a divisor of $|H|$.

If the gcd$([G:N],|H|)=1$, then $[NH:N]=1$,

> since this last index divides both $[G:N]$ and $|H|$. But this is equivalent to $NH=N$, that is $H \subseteq N$.

Now you are left with proving $(*)$. You can use an isomorphism theorem: $NH/N \cong H/(N \cap H)$, I leave this to you.

Bonus remark: it gets more interesting when gcd$([G:H],[G:N])=1$, then $G=NH$. Can you show that?

Comment: I still don't see how to relate $[NH:N]$ with $|H|$ and $[G:N]$ from those equations.

Comment: I will edit with spoilers.

Comment: Thanks. I don't need to find out what happens if $([G:H],[G:N])=1$ but if $(|H|,[G:N])=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Proving that $NH$ is a subgroup of $G$ should be easy. Now the homomorphism theorem says there is an isomorphism
$$
\frac{NH}{N}\to\frac{H}{H\cap N}
$$
which gives the first divisibility relation you're looking for.

By Lagrange's theorem
$$
\frac{|G|}{|N|}=\frac{|G|}{|NH|}\frac{|NH|}{|N|}.
$$
so you get the second relation.

If a number divides two coprime numbers, the number is…